# Will a subsection of a topologically sorted graph be sorted in the same order as the rest of the graph?

Tags: graph-theory

If I have a directed graph without any loops like this:

[image]

And I topologically sorted the nodes I would get something like: A, B, D, C, E.
If I remove node A and then topologically sorted the remaining nodes then I would get something like: B, D, C, E.
If I only ever remove a node that isn't referenced or I remove a node along with all of the nodes that reference it then will the remaining nodes always be in the same order? Under what circumstances would this rule be violated?

Thanks,

Joe

Comment: Topological sorting is a loosely specified algorithm. So a valid topological sorter could do something quite different on a subgraph compared with what it does to the containing graph. In practice, implementations are likely to have more stable properties. But that's implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from Wikipedia, we have that a topological ordering is an ordering of the vertices such that for every directed edge $uv$ from vertex $u$ to vertex $v$, $u$ comes before $v$ in the ordering. By this definition, if you remove a vertex $w$ from the ordering, the ordering is still a topological ordering of the graph $G-w$. As an aside, Rob Arthan's observation still holds, a digraph can have multiple topological orderings. Thus, some algorithm might not find that exact topological ordering on the subgraph, but it does indeed exist.